# Inconsistent results between gdalWarp (with cutline) and rasterio.mask

Tags: gdal, clip, gdalwarp, rasterio

Cropping with GDAL cutline vs Rasterio.mask with `crop=True` results in arrays with different sizes (by one row). I've tested the different Rasterio options but no luck.  I'm hoping to match the GDAL result with Rasterio.

MWE

```
import numpy as np
from osgeo import gdal, gdalconst
import rasterio as rio
import rasterio.mask as rmask
from shapely import wkt
import geopandas as gpd

# create the full dataset
width  = 3860
height = 2456 

arr_full = np.ones([height, width])
gt_full  = (-78.17458333333333, 0.000833333333333334, 0.0, 36.16291666666667, 0.0, -0.0008333333333333337)

dst_ds  = 'tmp.GTiff'
ds_full = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff').Create(dst_ds, width, height, 1, gdalconst.GDT_Int16)
ds_full.SetGeoTransform(gt_full)
ds_full.FlushCache()
del ds_full


# create masking polygon
poly = 'POLYGON ((-78.1644680561375 35.7970509557452, -77.1711839222526 ' \
               '35.9478757091113, -77.1469808399121 35.8397057740065, '\
               '-76.253905065698 35.9680947554346, -76.2662904527993 '\
               '36.0263570570668, -75.3546636103786 36.1500052682964, '\
               '-75.35053719786562 36.12949311936775, -76.1966148671565 '\
               '36.0146931854983, -76.1843924645653 35.9577022873936, '\
               '-77.2159963652384 35.8093521182806, -77.2408669577128 '\
               '35.918233797193, -78.1600656196335 35.7786235154726, '\
               '-78.16232638493148 35.787990354817566, -78.1644680561375 '\
               '35.7970509557452))'

poly = wkt.loads(poly)

# write for gdal
dst_poly  = 'tmp.GeoJSON'
gdf       = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=[poly]).to_file(dst_poly)
del gdf


with rio.open(dst_ds) as ds:
    rio_crop, rio_transform = rmask.mask(ds, [poly], crop=True, all_touched=True)

# this produces a warning but can be ignored, as source raster in full program has matching SRS and same result follows
gdal_crop_ds = gdal.Warp('', dst_ds, format="MEM", xRes=gt_full[1], yRes=gt_full[-1], cutlineDSName=dst_poly, 
                                            outputBounds=poly.bounds)
gdal_crop = gdal_crop_ds.ReadAsArray()

print (rio_crop.squeeze().shape, gdal_crop.shape)
```

Result: (447, 3377) (446, 3377)

Comment: As per the [help/behavior] please do not include chit chat like statements of appreciation within your posts.

Answer (score 1):

You ask rasterio to use option "all touched" so maybe you should try the same with gdalwarp. Documentation must be searched in two steps, the main document https://gdal.org/programs/gdalwarp.html has a link in warp options `-wo` and it points to https://gdal.org/api/gdalwarp_cpp.html#_CPPv4N15GDALWarpOptions16papszWarpOptionsE

> **CUTLINE_ALL_TOUCHED**: This defaults to FALSE, but may be set to TRUE to
> enable ALL_TOUCHEd mode when rasterizing cutline polygons. This is
> useful to ensure that that all pixels overlapping the cutline polygon
> will be selected, not just those whose center point falls within the
> polygon.

Search from the GDAL Python API documentation the correct way to add the warping option `CUTLINE_ALL_TOUCHED=TRUE` into your code. Or altertively use `all_touched=False` with rasterio.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried to say that I did test the other rasterio options (including all_touched=False) to no avail. Using the GDAL warping option actually results in a new size: (446, 3378)

Comment: Add the both "all touched" rasters and the geometry into a viewer, zoom very close to the extreme N-S-E-W locations and try to find out which program selects additional pixels or leaves out pixels which should be selected. Maybe that can lead into a bug report. I do not believe that you can do anything more as a user because the algorithms are making the selection.

Comment: Discussion moved to: https://rasterio.groups.io/g/main/topic/inconsistent_results_between/90922761?p=,,,20,0,0,0::recentpostdate/sticky,,,20,2,0,90922761,previd%3D1651790161430257572,nextid%3D1635812415644559462&previd=1651790161430257572&nextid=1635812415644559462